# When uninstall nativescript plugin and run 'tns run android' has failed

Tags: plugins, nativescript, uninstallation

### I'm devloping a nativescript plugin.when I want to change something with the plugin at index.js. so I uninstall the plugin and  explanatory note the plugin code in app project.Then I run  'tns run android' ,It's some error display:

`...
Merged dex #46 (1 defs/1.3KiB)
Merged dex #47 (1 defs/1.4KiB)
Merged dex #48 (2513 defs/3231.2KiB)
Result is 2560 defs/4103.9KiB. Took 0.1s
:buildMetadata
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class android.support.v7.widget.SnapHelper$2 conflict: D:\app\toast-test\platforms\android\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\F0F1F2\debu
        at com.telerik.metadata.ClassRepo.addToCache(ClassRepo.java:21)
        at com.telerik.metadata.Builder.build(Builder.java:40)
        at com.telerik.metadata.Generator.main(Generator.java:44)
:buildMetadata FAILED`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 41.154 secs
Command D:\app\toast-test\platforms\android\gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

How can I rebuild my app success after delete some plugins in project?
and how to update the nativescript plugin to new version?

Comment: Please edit your question.  It is difficult to determine what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing a plugin with native dependencies in the form of `.aar` or `.jar` (those include plugins downloaded through a remote plugin repository like maven) in NativeScript 2.4 you need to re-add the platform.

`tns plugin remove nativescript-plugin
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android / tns run/build android`

With the coming `2.5` release clearing any traces of the old plugin will be done by the CLI and no manual steps should be required besides simply removing the plugin from your project.

Comment: I upgraded the tns,but the version is 2.4.2 now.when the 2.5 version publish?